# hash table with 2D array

Tags: java, hashtable, multidimensional-array

I have been asked to create hash table using 2D array. I did it how ever in my put method there is something wrong in my understanding 2D array have to have two loops to do the implementing here is my put code i cannot insert anything.

```
 public class Array2DHashTable<K, V> {
    // here is my variable and my constructor. 
     // Array2DHashTable(int tableSize){ table = (Entry[][]) new HashEntry[tableSize]     [COLUMN_SIZE]; 
    //numItems = 0; }

    public void put(K key, V value){
       int hash= key.hashCode() % ROW_SIZE;
        int seenIt = hash;
       int j;
      for(j=0;j<COLUMN_SIZE;j++){
        while(table[hash][j] != null && table[hash][j].getKey().equals(key)){
          hash= ( hash+1)%ROW_SIZE;
          if(hash == seenIt) return;
          }
       }
      table[hash][j] = new HashEntry(key,value);
      numItems++;
    }

}


class HashEntry<K, V>  implements Entry<K, V>  {

  // all the variables and gutter and setter 
}
```

Comment: What is `COLUMN_SIZE` and `ROW_SIZE`?

Comment: these static numbers ROW_SIZE given to me. which is = 10, and COLUMN_SIZE  i put a random number which is 5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to overwrite the value if you find the same key (instead of changing the hash). Below is the code which does that.

```
    public void put(K key, V value){
      int hash= key.hashCode() % ROW_SIZE;
      int seenIt = hash;
      int j;
      for(j=0;j<COLUMN_SIZE;j++){
        while(table[hash][j] != null){
          if (table[hash][j].getKey().equals(key)) // overwrite the value
            hash=(hash+1)%ROW_SIZE;
        }
      }
      table[hash][j] = new HashEntry(key,value);
      numItems++;
    }
```

Comment: i triad it but it's not working because in my set method i just set value without key

Comment: You are setting the whole HashEntry there. So I suppose you can use the value from there.

Comment: the problem is when i add it cannot add it gave me an error on this line table[hash][j] = new HashEntry(key,value);

Comment: Can you provide me the whole implementation here for HashEntry. I can run this and let you know.

Comment: you mean the whole program or just the main method